# Amazon Ec2 Elastic IP - Outbound IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make a kind of proxy using elastic IPs on my Amazon EC2 instance. My question is, say I associate an elastic IP to my Amazon instance, and then I make an outbound connection from my EC2 instance to a server, say www.yahoo.com.

What IP address will www.yahoo.com see, the original Amazon EC2 server IP or the elastic IP I have associated to it?

Sorry if this is a basic question, but this is all new to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If an elastic IP is associated with an EC2 instance, that's the instance's external IP.

You can demonstrate this by doing `curl canhazip.com` in the command line.

Comment: Does this apply to VPC's? My outgoing IP does not appear to be the same as the Elastic IP applied to the main interface.

Comment: @JohnMcKim Yes, it applies to VPCs. The only caveat is sometimes you'll have your VPC subnet going through a NAT instance rather than directly.

Comment: If you are going through a NAT instance, does that subvert the EIP outbound?

Comment: @flickerfly Yes, you'd be showing up as the NAT instance's EIP.

Comment: @flickerfly If you want an instance (within a VPC) to use its assigned EIP, you'll want to put it into a subnet of its own that has 0.0.0.0/0 (or whatever is needed toward internet) route going through an internet gateway if your instances are otherwise configured to use either AWS-provided NAT, or an EC2-based NAT of your own.